# Migrating Hibernate3 to Hibernate5, Formatter class

Tags: hibernate, upgrade, hibernate-5.x, hibernate3

How can I edit this piece of code used with hibernate 3 in order to corresponds to hibernate 5.6.1 version.

I see that Formatter is now an interface with one single method.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For "basic SQL statements (DML + query)", please "try":

```java
Formatter formatter = new org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.BasicFormatterImpl();
formatter.format(query);
```

[BasicFormatterImpl javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/internal/BasicFormatterImpl.html)

For "DDL SQL statements", please:

```java
Formatter formatter = org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.DDLFormatterImpl.INSTANCE;
formatter.format(query);
```

[DDLFormatterImpl javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/internal/DDLFormatterImpl.html)

For "indent-/initialString" please consider a custom implementation, you can base on((/see source code of) the mentioned:

- [BasicFormatterImpl(main branch)](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/internal/BasicFormatterImpl.java)
- [DDLFormatterImpl(main branch)](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/internal/DDLFormatterImpl.java)